# How to sum totals meeting multiple criteria across several columns in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have five columns:

Agent, Result, Gift1, Gift2, Amount.

They populate with agent names, a code like Credit Card, Check, Other (and other options too that would need to be ignored) for Result, Yes or No for Gift1 or Gift2, and a dollar amount in the Amount column.

If Gift1 OR Gift2 (one or the other, or both) are answered YES, AND the result is Credit Card, Check or Other ONLY (there are other result codes), I want to double the Amount and keep a running tally, based on Agent. It should only be doubled once regardless of whether or not both are answered Yes.

So far I can figure out how to make it work with a helper column, which I'm trying to avoid. The purpose is that I'm trying to build a report and dump the data into Sheet2 and have the columns update automatically. I'm trying to make it as easy as possible and avoid manual updates.

Any thoughts? Can it be done?

Comment: Could you please post sample data and expected result?

Comment: Thanks, but someone wrote a macro for me to accomplish this. I think what I wanted to do was a bit too robust for strictly formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(OR(C2="Yes",D2="Yes"),IF(OR(B2="Credit Card",B2="Check",B2="Other"),E2*2,""),"")
```

This example has the fields you mentioned in columns A-E with the formula entered into cell F2 and copied down.  If the criteria is not met, then the result is blank.

[image]

Comment: That works if there is only one occurrence. I have hundreds of lines where there could be multiple matching gifts and need to keep a running total. I actually had help with using a macro to do it but didn’t know if there was a way to do it with strictly formulas.

Comment: By multiple occurrences, do you mean the same agent can have more than one row, and that is your challenge, getting the running total by agent?  Is the final outcome you are looking for to be a column for the agent name and a column for their grand total?